# What is the first name of Bainbridge?

Tags: type-theory, authorship

Bainbridge coauthored the paper `Functorial Polymorphism' with Freyd, Scedrov and Scott ([DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975(90)90151-7)). What is his/her first name?

Comment: I am curious, what is the purpose of this question?

Comment: To answer literally, there is no specific purpose other than knowing the name. For a more complete answer, I think I felt slightly guilty by having other names in the same entry but leaving only an abbreviation for this name. (Thanks for correcting the typo, by the way.)

Comment: I would say that if an author consistently writes his name as "E.S. Bainbridge" on publications, then he wants to be referred to as "E.S. Bainbridge". I know other scientists who prefer to use only an initial for their first name. Notice that in the tech report below E.S. is handwritten next to Edwin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on a quick search through the University of Michigan library catalog, I'm pretty sure it's "Edwin"; see, for example, this technical report ["A Class of Sequential Sampling Problems Arising in Certain Learning Situations" (1967)](http://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/3366/bab0803.0001.001.pdf?sequence=5&isAllowed=y).

Comment: Did you find out what the "S." stood for?

Comment: @a3nm Sorry, I have no clue.

Answer (score 5):

I knew him as a mentor back in the day.  In person he went by "Stewart Bainbridge".  Which also answers the question asked by @a3nm about what the "S" stands for.  I never heard about the "Edwin" so presumably it was a given name he wasn't fond of.